# Which is the best way to create a Texture Animation in Opengl 1 using Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, opengl, animation

I want to create a simple animation that shows a butterfly / a bird that flies using OpenGL, but I do not know how to approach the problem.

It would be a good solution to create a texture with two images to represent the animation since the animation is a small one?  And if so, how should i exchange the pictures between them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First load texture image by calling `glTexImage2D` the other time load images to texture which already exists, using `glTexSubImage2D`, which is significantly faster than `glTexImage2D` call, and is very suitable for this type of animation.

Information from specification:

```
void glTexSubImage2D(
    GLenum target,  
    GLint level,  
    GLint xoffset,  
    GLint yoffset,  
    GLsizei width,  
    GLsizei height,  
    GLenum format,  
    GLenum type,  
    const GLvoid * data
);
```

> `glTexSubImage2D` redefines a contiguous subregion of an existing
> two-dimensional texture image. The texels referenced by data replace
> the portion of the existing texture array with `x` indices `xoffset`
> and `xoffset + width - 1`  , inclusive, and y indices `yoffset` and
> `yoffset + height - 1`  , inclusive. This region may not include any
> texels outside the range of the texture array as it was originally
> specified.

In case to get full texture image exchange you simply specify `xoffset` and `yoffset` equal to zero.

You may specify the texture names array like

```
char* textureNames[10] = { "...", "...", ..., "..." };
```

Then for texture data

```
GLbyte* textureData[10]; // 10 texture instances
```

load texture data with `LoadTGA` rutine with automatical memory allocation

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    textureData[i] = LoadTGA(
        textureNames[i],
        /*... TEXTURE PARAMS MUST BE THE SAME FOR ALL IMAGES */
    );
}
```

Loading first image

```
glTexImage2D(
    GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_RGB, 0, width, height, 0,
    format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureData[0]
);
```

in some rendering function

```
static int imageIndex = 0;

glTexSubImage2D(
    GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, width, height,
    format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureData[imageIndex]
);

imageIndex++;

if (imageIndex == 10) // max index reached
    imageIndex = 0;
```

Consider you use small amount of frames (textures), I suggest you to add some delay to rendering as the pictures will be changing extremely fast.

Or as you want to achieve realtime rendering speed, you can use some sort of async timer to switch between texture indices.

Or as you just want to change between 2 separate textures, I have answer previously how [randomly apply textures to the surfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33989111/5348281). So it can be simply done by creating 2 simple 2d textures.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    g_pnTextures[i] = loadTGA(textureNames[i], g_pnTextures[i]);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_COMBINE);
    glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_COMBINE_RGB, GL_MODULATE);
}
```

`g_pnTextures` must be `GLuint` type array. Texture generation call will be like `glGenTextures(2, g_pnTextures)`.

Then sequentially change its index. And bind them to some surface.

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, g_pnTextures[imageIndex++]);
if (imageIndex == 10) // max index reached
    imageIndex = 0;

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
// specify texture coords
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex2f(-1.0f, -1.0f);
// specify texture coords
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex2f(1.0f, -1.0f);
// specify texture coords
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
// specify texture coords
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex2f(-1.0f, 1.0f);

glEnd();
```

As you can see this loadTGA function returns memory buffer instead of OpenGL texture identifier (which causes the problems with value conversion).

Notice: The last techinque can be applied to the small amount of textures. If you want to achieve movie effect visualization or GIF animation, the first technique is the best way.

Comment: I can not load the texture using loadTGA  in textureData, because it tells me that i can not convert from int to GLbyte*

Comment: @Maria: Since you created 2 different textures, the other strategy to change textures can by applied.

Comment: Here is my code :
`code`
 char* textureNames[2] = { "Textures\\bird1.tga", "Textures\\bird2.tga"};
 GLuint bird1Texture;
 GLuint bird2Texture; 
 GLbyte* textureData[2]; // 2 texture instances

 glGenTextures(1, &bird1Texture);
 glGenTextures(1, &bird2Texture);
 //here is the error
 textureData[0] = loadTGA(textureNames[0], bird1Texture);
 textureData[0] = loadTGA(textureNames[1], bird2Texture);

 glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_RGB, 0, 10, 10, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureData[0]);  Sorry, but i can not indent the code ..

Comment: @Maria: This problem is caused because your loadTGA function is like black box. As I can see from you post it loads TGA image and call `glBindTexture` and `glTexImage` so you actualy cannot access to texture data buffer.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've used the second method and it worked perfectly!

Comment: @Maria: Glad for you! Good luck!